# how to draw a line from a div to another div on base of id

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently trying to draw a diagonal line between the bottom mid of one div to the top mid of another by using id of divs.

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

I want to draw a line between these two divs

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: why is this tagged as "php"? There's also no "js" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this, using svg?

```css
#wrap {
  display: flex;
}

#first {
  background:grey;
  width:45%
}

#second {
  background:grey;
  width:45%
}

#line {
 stroke:rgb(255,0,0);
 stroke-width:2
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="first">first</div>
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <line x1="0" y1="75" x2="100" y2="25" id="line" />
  </svg>
  <div id="second">second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can i get like i can connect two divs with their id like i have many other divs to connect so i wish to connect them by their id as i have to draw a flowchart  manually fetching values from mysql database